# PHP Includes within <head> rendering in <body>

Tags: php, html

So, I have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <?php include("/common/includes.php"); ?>
    <?php include("/common/meta-data.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include("/common/general_notifications.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
    <?php include("/common/header.php"); ?>
    <div class="well">
        <h3>Welcome to your portal!</h3>        
    </div>
    <?php include("/common/footer.php"); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where `includes.php` is:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering (note the ob_flush to send the output buffer is implicit so can (and has) been omitted)
require_once("/dbase_connection.php");
require_once("/common/tools.php");
$objConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And `meta-data.php` is:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo "//".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/store_admin/common/functions.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo "//".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo "//".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/css/admin.css">
```

When I check this code in Firebug (or any of the dev tools in **IE**, **Chrome** & **Firefox**), all the content that should be within the `<head>` tags is showing in the `<body>` tags!

If I remove the includes and copy the text into the main file, it's working as expected. I've checked the encoding (using Notepad++) and all the files are set to `UTF-8-BOM`.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

The code from the view source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>This is the </title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="admin/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="admin/js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="../e360/admin/js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="admin/common/functions.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin/css/admin.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin/css/store_admin.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="message-bar" id="message-bar-notify"></div>
<div class="container">
    <header>
    <img src="/images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" />
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <h1 style="font-weight:bold; font-size:22px; text-align:center;">Portal</h1>
</header>
    <div class="well">
        ***content***
    </div>
    </br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The includes.php file should be at the very top of the page, before you begin the html,  because you output content then call ob_start()...

Comment: It's not php that does it, it's firefox that is fixing your markup.

Comment: There has to be content or an element that isn't allowed in the head somewhere. It doesn't seem to be in the code you've shared though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox rendering HTML incorrect sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318941/firefox-rendering-html-incorrect-sometimes)

Comment: What is the exact HTML that is produced by all this...? The *raw* HTML, not Firefox' live DOM element inspector.

Comment: convert the files to UTF8 WITHOUT BOM. Thank me later.

Comment: This PHP should give you a warning when you call `session_start`, since you already outputted the start of the page.

Comment: @STTLCU I think you commented on the wrong question. ;)

Comment: JohnBupit: it's not just Firefox - IE & Chrome too. RamRaider: I've moved includes.php  to the top, but no difference.

Comment: Does your actual page have a .PHP extension? Sounds silly but this *is* exactly what would happen if that were the case...

Comment: @iamgory: yes, it does.

Comment: Just to make this explicit again: the first thing to check here is the raw HTML output. View the page's source code in your browser (again, not Firebug et al., *View Source*), or `curl` the raw response on the command line or such. If that doesn't make it obvious why the `</head>` gets terminated prematurely, post that HTML here. With the given information there's not a lot we can do.

Comment: Move this line `<?php include("/common/includes.php"); ?>` above this line `<!doctype html>`

Comment: @deceze: raw code has been posted. It looks ok, but the page isn't rendering correctly!

Comment: By what metric does the code you posted "look ok"? That's nowhere near valid HTML.

Comment: @deceze: copy/pasted the wrong bits...